# JavaFX multiple Groups per scene/ transparent Scene (not stage)

Tags: javafx-8

So I have a stage on which I am rendering a few arrays of imageviews, and the problem is that root.getChildren().remove(i); doesnt always remove the right item from the group.

One solution would be to have multiple groups in the scene, but the internet is kindly quiet about it so I dont even know if it can be done.

Another solution would be to have multiple scenes on the stage, and making all but the most bottom one transparent. The only information i've found is on making the entire stage transparent which doesnt help me at all in this case.

Or am I thinking in the wrong direction?

Example of how I add a clone object to the group (this code runs about every frame):

```
final ImageView ext = new ImageView();
ext.setTranslateX(move2.x);
ext.setTranslateY(move2.y);
ext.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(GPU.rotat,45, -70));
ext.setImage(thrustereffect);
root.getChildren().add(ext);
```

Comment: Why is `root.getChildren().remove(i)` not remove the right item? Can you use the `root.getChildren().remove(imageView)` method instead?

Comment: I tried that, using the object name but that completely gliches the  app, blocking controls and removing random things.

Comment: You need to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Perhaps its not directly apparent, but I'm not asking for a solution to a problem but how to use a scene with multiple groups or how to set up a transparent scene. That's why I didnt include one  of those.

Comment: The correct way to do it is to remove the object from the parent's list of children. If that's causing problems, you have something else wrong in our code.

Comment: The problem is I am adding ImageViews to the group that have the same name, as they are clones and I seem to be only able to remove them using the location in the group - example added.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition.OrientationType;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

  public class Mains extends Application{

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
  {
  final Group rootGroup = new Group();
  final Group subGroup1= new Group();

  rootGroup.getChildren().add( subGroup1 );

  final Scene scene = new Scene(rootGroup, 350, 550, Color.GHOSTWHITE);
  stage.setScene(scene);
  stage.setTitle("Animations");
  stage.show();

  final Path pathOn_rootGroup = new Path();
  final Path pathOn_subGroup1 = new Path();

  pathOn_rootGroup.getElements().add(new MoveTo( 0, 20 ) );
  pathOn_rootGroup.getElements().add(
         new CubicCurveTo( 30, 120, 30, 220, 520, 120) );

  pathOn_subGroup1.getElements().add(new MoveTo( 50, 50 ) );
  pathOn_subGroup1.getElements().add(
         new CubicCurveTo( 350, 20, 250, 240, 320, 240 ) );

  pathOn_rootGroup.setOpacity( 0.5 );
  pathOn_subGroup1.setOpacity( 0.5 );

  rootGroup.getChildren().add( pathOn_rootGroup );
  subGroup1.getChildren().add( pathOn_subGroup1 );

  final javafx.scene.shape.Circle rootGroup_shape = 
          new javafx.scene.shape.Circle();
  rootGroup_shape.setCenterX(50);
  rootGroup_shape.setCenterY(50);
  rootGroup_shape.setRadius(12.5);
  rootGroup_shape.setFill( Color.AQUA );

  final javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle subGroup1_shape = 
          new javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle();
  subGroup1_shape.setX(20);
  subGroup1_shape.setY(20);
  subGroup1_shape.setWidth(20);
  subGroup1_shape.setHeight(30);
  subGroup1_shape.setFill( Color.BLUEVIOLET );

  rootGroup.getChildren().add( rootGroup_shape );
  subGroup1.getChildren().add( subGroup1_shape );

  final PathTransition pathTransition_rootGroup = new PathTransition();
  pathTransition_rootGroup.setDuration(Duration.seconds(8.0));
  pathTransition_rootGroup.setDelay(Duration.seconds(.5));
  pathTransition_rootGroup.setPath(pathOn_rootGroup);
  pathTransition_rootGroup.setNode(rootGroup_shape);
  pathTransition_rootGroup.setOrientation(OrientationType.NONE);
  pathTransition_rootGroup.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
  pathTransition_rootGroup.setAutoReverse(true); 

  final PathTransition pathTransition_subGroup1 = new PathTransition();
  pathTransition_subGroup1.setDuration(Duration.seconds(8.0));
  pathTransition_subGroup1.setDelay(Duration.seconds(1.0));
  pathTransition_subGroup1.setPath(pathOn_subGroup1);
  pathTransition_subGroup1.setNode(subGroup1_shape);
  pathTransition_subGroup1.setOrientation(OrientationType.NONE);
  pathTransition_subGroup1.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
  pathTransition_subGroup1.setAutoReverse(true);

  final ParallelTransition parallelTransition =
     new ParallelTransition(pathTransition_rootGroup, pathTransition_subGroup1 );
  parallelTransition.play(); 
 }// end start()

public static void main(final String[] arguments)
{
  Application.launch(arguments);
}// end main method
}// end class Main
```